# Google Analytics doesn't show data older than 3 days

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I set up a basic Google Firebase integration for my Android mobile app, it worked fine for a couple of days but then suddenly the Google Analytics console started showing the data just for the most recent 3 days. It's been a consistent behavior for the past week - everyday when I check the data I only see the most recent 3 days. And the older data that was present the day before is missing.

This is my second mobile app that I integrated with Google Firebase and the first one doesn't seem to have this issue.
I tried searching for similar issues on the web but nothing relevant comes up. I also went through all the possible settings in Analytics console, but nothing seems suspicious.

What can be the cause of this?

UPD: I found this thread in the meantime https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/83254216?hl=en Maybe there'll be some resolution there

Comment: Did you add any filters? I'm facing the same problem on a fresh GAccount and everyone is telling me to check filters

Comment: @NicosKaralis If you're talking about the filters on the top of the Analytics page next to the "Add Filter" button, then there are none there.